# How do I disable tabs in Firefox (so it can only hold one page at a time)?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

For the sake of simplicity, concentration, single-tasking, etc, how do I disable tabs in Firefox (make tabs as non-existent of a feature as possible)?

- Preferences?
- about:config?
- userChrome.css?
- Plugin/AddOn/Extension?

Comment: Which of those have you tried? What were your problems?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Customize Page:

- Remove the new tab button (Right click the + and select "remove from toolbar")

Go to Options:

- Under General uncheck "Open links in tabs instead of new windows"

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to fully disable tabs in Firefox.

There used to be an old plugin called "TabKiller" but this stopped being updated a LONG time ago and it certainly not compatible with Firefox Quantum.

You may be able to force links to open in new windows rather than new tabs, but this does not actually disable the tabs, it only changes link behavior.

There are several Mozilla support form posts on this:

- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/908814 - This one notes the TabKiller plugin is no longer updated.
- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/944667 - This one references the TabKiller plugin.